# c++ object and "undefined reference to" not agree with duplicated

Tags: c++, object, cygwin, undefined-reference

Hello all :) It was a forgotten double declaration with a "extern".

## Problem

I believe it is a problem of object between differents files or a problem of "&" or "*"

I have the error line:

```
-lws2_32/tmp/ccBWAJ1F.o: dans la fonction « Z2iav »:/home/myfolder/ia.hpp:217: référence indéfinie vers « union_range »collect2: erreur: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
```

(undefined reference to union_range  with 1 code state execution)

I am at 95% sure that the error is from my use of a CarSet object (union_range)
in ia.hpp in valeur_main_board_range(moment()+1,union_range)

I have a very close function valeur_main_board(moment()+1) without any error.

## ia.hpp

the error is here:
 **int valeur_main = valeur_main_board_range(moment()+1,union_range);**

in my file ia.hpp

```
#include "variable_calcule.hpp"

extern std::set<CardSet> union_range, resultat, range_joueur;
// the error was the "extern" to remove
void ia() 
{
std::set<CardSet> union_range, resultat, range_joueur;
for (int j=0; j<10; j++) 
    {
    range_joueur=range_action(action[0][j][1],j);
    set_union(union_range.begin(),union_range.end(),range_joueur.begin(),range_joueur.end(),std::inserter(resultat,resultat.begin()));
    union_range=resultat;
    }

    int valeur_main = valeur_main_board_range(moment()+1,union_range); // BUG HERE
}
```

## valeur_main_board_range() code (using union_range)

union_range include from     #include "variable_calcule.hpp"
in include  #include "analyse_action.hpp"

```
#include "CardSet.h"
using namespace pokerstove;
using namespace std;

int valeur_main_board_range(int nb_carte, std::set<CardSet> &range)     { 

int dessus=0;

    [...]

return dessus;  
}
```

If I find the answer I will remove unnecessary code for future readers. For the moment I prefer put too much... But if you want I remove or add code just ask :)

Thank you for your reading :)

Comment: that is too much code for an typical undefined reference error.

Comment: tl;dr; nail a point for your problem!!

Comment: I have edited following your recommendations.
I have search tl; and dr; on google but do not understand.
It was not a duplicate: (it was a forgotten "extern" i didn't seen since 3 day...) but your link remains interesting...
Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In presented code snippets I found out union_range only inside function ia where this name is well-defined.

```
void ia() 
{
analyse_action();
std::set<CardSet> union_range, resultat, range_joueur;
```

Here union_range is a local variable of type `std::set<CardSet>.` 
So you showed irrelevant code.

Comment: Thanks to you I have find the error: I was searching in the wrong place: 
the error was on the declaration
I have forget to remove "extern" from a past and copy
extern std::set<CardSet> union_range, resultat, range_joueur; .
Your answer has helped me to search in the right place with a control + F. Thank you so much!